# Nginx internally call another request and return that request data

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am using nginx and lua to parse my rest api (https://openresty-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Lua_Nginx_API/) . I am trying to internally call another api inside my rest call which is a different server and return that response. But it is getting empty response always. Below is my config, I am requesting for /student any help is highly appreciable

```
location /student {
    content_by_lua '
    local str = "test"
    local res = ngx.location.capture("/detail",{method = ngx.HTTP_POST, body = str})
    ngx.say(str)
    ';
}
location /detail {
    set $target '104.28.17.1/post';
    set $pass 'Basic Y2l28=';
    lua_need_request_body on;
    content_by_lua '
    proxy_set_header          Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header          X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    #access_by_lua '
    proxy_set_header Authorization $pass;
    proxy_set_header Content-Type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    proxy_set_header Accept '*/*';
    proxy_set_header Connection 'keep-alive';
    proxy_pass http://$target;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use resty.http to do a call in lua and write it to the body.
Below for a https call with authentication to an api:

```
-- load requirements 
http = require "resty.http"

local function api_request(ip, api_host, api_hostname, api_cred, api_url)
  local httpc  = http.new()
  httpc:set_timeout(500)
  path = api_host .. string.format(api_url, ip)
  local response, err = httpc:request_uri(path,{
      method = "GET",
      headers = {
          ["Authorization"] ="Basic " .. api_cred,
          ["Host"] = api_hostname,
      },
      ssl_verify = false,
  })
  return response
end
```